# Android Studio: Make the only two user see only the value in firebase realtime database and the others will not

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an app that can trade items. Here is the situation, the current user will post an item then the other user will offer the item then if the current user likes the offered item he will take the offer. When the offer is taken I want the current user and other users to see the item. In short two people can only see the post and the other will not. The poster and the offerer can only see their transaction.

The poster and the offer can only see the post if the poster takes the offer

I use this reference but all users can see the post [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btcc7.jpg)

Comment: What are you using, Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: Im only using realtime database

Comment: So do you need to perform a query based on two properties? For example, when an offer can be seen by only two users. Something like a join?

Comment: Yes, only two users can see the item, the one that post the item and the offerer

Comment: You can see my reference that i added in my question

Comment: And the last question. So do you want to get all trades where `offereeName` equals `Juan` and `offererName` equals `Pedro`, right?

Comment: Yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Firebase Realtime database does not support queries on multiple properties. It only supports queries on a single-child property. So there is no way you can get all trades where `offereeName` equals `Juan` and `offererName` equals `Pedro` in a single go.

To overcome this situation you'll have to create an extra field that should hold the value of both fields. So your node should look like this:

```
db-root
 |
 --- Trade
      |
      --- -NH-Y...mH9e
            |
            --- offereeName: "Juan"
            |
            --- offererName: "Pedro"
            |
            --- offereeName_offererName: "Juan_Pedro"
```

As you can see, the `offereeName_offererName` filed combines the values that you want to filter on. So a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tradeRef = db.child("Trade");
Query query = tradeRef.orderByChild("offereeName_offererName").equalTo("Juan_Pedro");
```

Will work perfectly fine.

Unlike the Firebase Realtime Database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). This means that a query such as the one below is allowed without the need to create a combined field:

```
tradeRef.whereEqualTo("offereeName", "Juan").whereEqualTo("offererName", "Pedro");
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea i will work on this unfortunately i cant vote for now but thank you for helping

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: You'll be able to do that when you have at least 15 points of reputation.

Comment: Hey Paulo. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?